# How to import 'route.h' from the SDK into my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My application works fine in the iOS simulator (running iOS 8.1).

The build target of the app is for iOS version 7.0.

When I try to run my app on my real iPhone (running iOS 7.0), the build fails- the reason being, `route.h` file is missing.

**How can I extract this file from the iOS simulator SDK present in my mac, and add it to my project?**

Basically, I'm trying to run my app on my phone, without updating the phone to version 8.1.

As I'm new to iOS development, I have no idea where the SDK is even stored on the drive, or how to access it.

(I'm using Xcode 6.)

Comment: Is route.h a file you created?

Comment: No, it's in the iOS 8.1 SDK. I can see it when I cmd+click the place where it is referenced. I don't know how to copy the file that gets opened, to add to my project.

Comment: Where is the referenced location? If it's nested as part of iOS 8.1, it will probably have other files as dependancies/imports.

Comment: I found a lot of questions about that file missing and the voted answer was to just add it to the project. Anyways, I solved my problem by just updating my device to 8.1. Thanks for your time.